# Qt Quick Controls 2 [Material]: Как добиться такого результата?

Tags: qt, qml

Здравствуйте. Можете ли Вы мне подсказать, как добиться такого результата стилей как на этом скрине?: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал сделать Theme=Dark и Accent=Teal, но именно этот сине-голубой цвет получается очень ярким. Пожалуйста, какие сочетания тем и цветов можно добиться такого результата?

Answer (score 0):

Цвет можно вычислить если сделать копию экрана и ткнуть в нужно место пипеткой в Paint (windows), данный цвет в qml: #009688

Google утверждает, что это Dark Cyan